# Retrieve FORM_DATA_ID using Orbeon API

Tags: orbeon, formbuilder

We are trying to integrate Orbeon Forms(Form Builder and Form Runner enabled) with our existing application and we are doing the integration with the URL's. We have two part requirements

1. When clicked on create form on our web application we have to invoke
   the Orbeon form builder new form with application name and form name
   pre populated as we already have that context. The form
   builder(https://localhost:8443/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/new) takes
   Application Name, Form Name and Form Title.  Is there any
   configuration that can be used to pre populate those values or an
   API where i can create a default form structure?
2. In our web application we want to list all the published forms the
   user has access to and that we were able to get access using the API
   `fr/service/persistence/form/CCM` but this API doesn't return the
   `FORM_ID` which can be used to edit the form.  Is there any other API
   that i can use to get access to the `FORM_ID`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Allowing the app name, form name, and title to be passed to the new page, so you can bypass the initial Form Builder dialog is a feature [planned for the upcoming 4.10](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2245).
2. The [deployed forms metadata](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api#TOC-Deployed-forms-metadata) you're referring to returns that information in the `<application-name>` and `<form-name>` elements of the response. Then, if you want to list the form data for each deployed form definition, you can call the [search API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api#TOC-Search) to return all the document ids for each app/form name the user has access to.

Comment: Issue [#2245](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2245) is now implemented and [documented](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Builder-~-Integration#bypassing-the-new-form-dialog) for Orbeon Forms 4.10. See also this [forum discussion](http://discuss.orbeon.com/New-form-URL-in-builder-can-I-include-appname-and-formname-td4659960.html).